# Running many Rails app instances with third party dependencies in on a single machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I am trying to set up a local "testbed" for the developers at the firm I work out. There are several developers working on a single server app and frequently need to deploy their branches for client side testing. Currently, all these deploys occur on an offsite server with a separate application instance per deploy.

I would like to create a homebrewed solution and have been looking at services such as [pow.cx](http://pow.cx). This is great and all, but the server app requires multiple external services such as redis and memcached, both of which require separate ports. I could, in principle, manually create additional config files for each separate instance, but this is difficult in practice and requires a lot more bookkeeping in terms of juggling environments.

Being a bad system admin, I was wondering if there was a simpler approach (i.e. virtual hosts) that would allow me to deploy each instance identically but behind, say, a different subdomain?

I realize this question is fairly demanding and I will certainly appreciate any advice I can get.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience. I have some simple application on one host. I use simple configurable tools: [passenger + nginx](http://www.modrails.com/install.html) as server ( to add new server you need to add 5 lines of code ), [Vlad the Deployer](http://rubyhitsquad.com/Vlad_the_Deployer.html) for deploying, [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) for different ruby version, bundler as tool for separating rails gem.

I have some servers: production, development, test. They are placed on different hdd on vps and have own domains to exclude any influence between servers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the easiest thing would be to have a bunch of VMs on that server, one per application instance. You could share some things (e.g. your database server) across your application instances if you wanted to.

You can automate of lot of this using something like [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com). One benefit of doing it this way is that it is then easy to move one particular VM to a dedicated machine if it needs it or for a new developer to use that VM for development.

Comment: Ah this looks very promising thanks. So far, I have set up a git server on the machine and I imagine if I get a bunch of VMs running, I can make a git hook to clone the appropriate branch in to the corresponding machine. Vagrant seems very useful.